# Как найти результат арифметического выражения?

Tags: c++

Как написать программу, которая определяет результат арифметического выражения, введенного пользователем?? Подскажите какими функциями пользоваться и какой приблизительный алгоритм. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Почитайте [Dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book) :-P

Answer (score 1):

Для вычисления математических выражений необходимо сначала записать их в [обратной польской записи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) (она так же известна как польская инверсная запись). Далее воспользоваться одним из готовых алгоритмов.